# Word VBA to print PDF and clear Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have half of the code working but the part that needs to clear Excel spreadsheet is not working somehow.

Name is equal to a bookmark.

Path of both docs are always the same.

Can someone help please?

I never used VBA in one app to do stuff in another app )

```
Sub Save_as_PDF()
Dim StrPath As String, StrName As String
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
With ActiveDocument
    StrPath = .Path & "\"
    StrName = .Bookmarks("Name").Range.Text
    .SaveAs2 FileName:=StrPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("StrPath & License certificate generation.xlsx")
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlSheet.Range("A2:J100").ClearContents
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Add `xlApp.Visible=True` after `Set xlApp...` to help your troubleshooting.

Comment: What does "not working" mean specifically?

Comment: `xlApp.Workbooks.Open(StrPath & "License certificate generation.xlsx")`

Comment: @TimWilliams, you are right. I put quote in a wrong place LOL
Now there is another issue. It open prompt to save Excel. I would like it to save it with the same name without asking me at all. It should be just a blink.
Please, what needs to be changed to avoid the prompt?
Thank you!

Comment: Try calling `xlWB.Save` and then `xlWB.Close`    You're not making your Excel instance visible though, so I'm surprised you see any prompt from Excel...

Comment: @TimWilliams, Now I got notification from Excel "A file named 'License certificate generation.xlsx' already exists
in this location. Do you want to replace it?"

Comment: What does `MsgBox(xlWB.FullName)` give you?  Is it what you expect?  Also check you don't have any hidden instances of excel running